# EF Core 5.0 Union Linq Query with sub selects not working

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

**Goal:**

I want to combine information from two tables (entityA & entityB) with different Properties to one unionDto. I am trying to implement this with a union operation to filter different entities in the Database at the same time.

But the structure I am using requires Versions which need to be filtered **before** the union query.

**Some Additional Information:**

So what I am trying to do in the last query is: First I project information from table **"entityA"** and **"entityB"** to a universal **"anonymous"** type (with union). Then I am trying to apply pagination and then I am trying to **"project"** the new anonymous result to a **UnionDto**. So this would result in one UnionDto which has **"information from 2 different tables"**.

I have created an example of my problem with two entities which have Versions:

**Entities:**

```
class entityA {
    public List<VersionA> Versions;
    public Guid CreatedBy;
}

class entityB {
    public List<VersionB> Versions;
    public Guid CreatedBy;
}

class VersionA {
    public string TitleA;
    public Instant EffectiveTo;
}

class VersionB {
    public string TitleB;
    public Instant EffectiveTo;
}

class UnionDto{
    public string Title;
    public Guid Creator;
}
```

**I am setting up the query like this:**

```
var queryA = databaseContext.Set<entityA>()
                .Select(entity => new
                {
                    Versions = entity.Versions
                        .Where(version => version.EffectiveTo > now)    /* Filtering newest entity Version */ 
                        .Select(versionDetail => new               /* Selecting only the Title of this Version */
                        {
                            Title = versionDetail.TitleA
                        })
                        .ToList(),
                    Creator = entity.CreatedBy,
                });

var queryB = databaseContext.Set<entityB>()
                .Select(entity => new
                {
                    Versions = entity.Versions
                        .Where(version => version.EffectiveTo > now)
                        .Select(versionDetail => new 
                        {
                            Title = versionDetail.TitleB
                        })
                        .ToList(),
                    Creator = entity.CreatedBy,
                });
```

**Executing the query:**

```
var unionDto = await queryA
                .Union(queryB)
                .Skip(0)
                .Take(20)
                .Select(x => new UnionDto
                {
                    Title= x.Versions.FirstOrDefault() == null ? null : 
                        x.Versions.FirstOrDefault().Title,
                    Creator= x.Creator,
                })
                .ToListAsync();
```

It seems like that i am not able to use sub selects inside a union query and I am getting the following error:

> Set operations: support when placed after client evaluation in
> projection #16243

I dont know, what I have to do to get around this issue, since I dont really want to go throught all of my entities seperatly with seperate Database queries.

Currently using Ef core Version: 5.0.100-preview

Now this is just an example. This would be required for at least 10 entities, which would result in high Database traffic if done for each entity seperatly.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do? That query is a bit convoluted and won't return what you think it will. In all currently supported SQL Server versions you can use temporal tables instead of adding and maintaining `Effective` columns. Even if you do want separate valid vs effective records, the ORM is *not* the place to apply temporal filtering. You should use a view for this. Apart from that, EF Core 5 introduced filtered Includes. You could use [query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) to apply temporal filtering transparently

Comment: An ORM's job is to Map Objects to Relational tables or views. It's *not* meant to implement triggers, temporal filtering, reporting queries, bulk operations. LINQ makes reporting queries a *bit* easier, but only up to a point. You should consider whether it makes sense to write this query in LINQ or in SQL, using your database's full feature set

Comment: What happens if you leave the .`ToList` out of the sub query `Select`s? Alternately, what if you commonize the entities without filtering, then filter the common entities? (e.g. delay the `Where().Select()` to after the `Union` ?

Comment: This query is very difficult to translate. You have here 2 Eager Loading queries which are hard to combine and I even can not imagine common solution for such case. Consider to rewrite your query into two separated queries.

Comment: There's no `x.Title` in the Selects that you Union.

Comment: Its not related to your problem directly, but why all your entities contains fields and not property? And why `CreatedBy` is string in your entity classes and `Creator` is Guid in you DTO class?

Comment: Would it be possible to create a View in the database that holds your query and use the result of that view in your linq query?

Comment: first u used Tolist in ur query, like NetMage suggests. it is possible. have you tried Concat. is there a way you can rather write the join rather than use projections.

Comment: my suggestion is try in 3.1 ef first then see if it works in 5

Comment: @GertArnold I am sorry. You are right.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This entire problem is only an example problem, which was created by me to portray the underlying union issue. I will look into temporary tables for that Effective columns thx. And I know about include filters coming with ef core 5. But i dont think they are required for the solution of this problem.

Comment: @NetMage The .ToList() cannot be taken out of the subSelects. I have also thought about the idea of using a common interface for all entityA and entityB, to be able to do what you suggest. It is somehow required to use Selects() after the .Union() to be able to work. But I am required to project different properties to the Title in each entityA and entityB. Therefore it is nessecary to use a Select inside of the queryA and queryB.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv since the real problem has more then 5 entities and this Db call is done in a lot situations, a seperate call for each entity would result in too much traffic. I would like to avoid that --> Thats why I am using Union in the first place.

Comment: @GertArnold you are totatly right with x.Title. I fixed that. But the real question I am having is concening the sub Select inside of a union, which does not work for me.

Comment: @atiyar you are right, CreatedBy should be a Guid. I fixed it. Thx

Comment: @CemYazici, I have no idea, how EF Core can generate SQL for such query. I'm developing LINQ provider `linq2db` for 6 years and know what I'm saying - very complicated. `Versions` is a Eager Loading property and usually EF Core adds additional join and then group entities on the client side. Here you have 2 Eager Loading queries which has to be correctly handled by materializer. Don't expect such miracle from still weak EF Core translator. Anyway maybe we can rewrite query to be performant if you give more concrete cases.

Comment: If you need only one Title from versions - it is another variant. We can modify your query.

Comment: This is a work for CTE and Views

Comment: Why can't the `ToList` be removed?

Comment: @NetMage sorry, you are totally right. you can remove the .ToList() my bad.

Comment: And if you take out `ToList`, what happens - do you get a different error?

Answer (score 5):

If you need only title of first version from each recordset, your query can be simplified and EF Core can translate this query.

```
 var queryA = 
    from entity in databaseContext.Set<entityA>()
    from version in entity.Versions
    where version.EffectiveTo > now
    select new 
    { 
       Title = version.Title, 
       Creator = entity.CreatedBy 
    }

 var queryB = 
    from entity in databaseContext.Set<entityB>()
    from version in entity.Versions
    where version.EffectiveTo > now
    select new 
    { 
       Title = version.Title, 
       Creator = entity.CreatedBy 
    }

 var versions = queryA.Union(queryB);

 var unionDto = await versions
            .Skip(0)
            .Take(20)
            .Select(x => new UnionDto
            {
                Title = x.Title,
                Creator = x.Creator,
            })
            .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, but doing this gives the following error :
**"Set operations over different store types are currently unsupported."** 
So I looked into this errormessage and it seems like this operation is currently not supported by ef core

Comment: What can I say. EF is still weak LINQ translator and even error message is weird. Let's rewrite query.

Comment: Updated answer with new query.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it looks like this does not work either. Same error. It seems, that it is generally not possible to use a subSelects inside of these union queries, so I will be forced to write a manuall SQL query for that. I know, that this is possilbe but I was trying to avoid it using Linq.

Comment: It is possible by using LINQ, just EF fails with Union. Just try my extension https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore and enjoy correctly generated SQL.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv this library you mentioned here is truly amazing, well done and thank you, it saved me from some unions that just did not want to work with .NET 5

Answer (score 0):

EF Union set
Tracked with [Set operations over non-entity projections with different facets Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19129)

Now fixed with EF8 Preview 3 as seen [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/29989)